# Using Zener diodes to limit the max RPM of wind turbine

Tags: over-voltage-protection, braking, windturbine

A windmill produces AC voltage, with increasing voltage as the turbine spins faster. If you know the max safe RPM, you could find the associated max safe voltage (V_safe). Additionally, when the leads of a turbine are shorted with each other, it induces a braking effect.

If you place a Zener diode with a V_safe breakdown voltage (maybe slightly lower for a safety margin), wouldn’t the AC voltage above V_safe go towards braking the turbine?
I’m interested because of two reasons:

1. Preventing the turbine from spinning itself apart.
2. The V_safe I’m interested in would actually be the max value of a switch mode buck converter.

[image: Really badly drawn turbine with two leads and two zener diodes]

Comment: Zener diodes are not meant to dissipate the power associated with the application you are describing.

Comment: What generator power level are you considering here? How does that compare with the largest Zener diode you've seen?

Comment: @vir, I just assumed the power would be dissipated as heat or the magnetic braking in the copper coils of the generator in the braking process.

Comment: @Transistor, this is all very hypothetical. But if I were to build anything like this, it'd be for a small wind turbine, maybe 100 watts.

Comment: 100 W might be achievable. I can find 50 W versions in stud-mount. I'm not sure that it's the right solution though.

Comment: Why not to place a bridge rectifier on generator output and clamp to battery so energy is stored rather than dissipated.

Comment: If you insist on dissipating use zener+power transistor so zener is not under high power stress.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický, my concern is if the batteries are full and nothing in the system is pulling a load. I understand that some wind turbine system enable some kind of large resistor to act as a load if the batteries are full and the turbine is spinning too fast. However, I was curious if the zener diode idea were feasibly because I wasn't sure how to set up the 'full battery' detection logic to enable some other loads. The zener diodes idea would be purely passive and act as a last line of defense in some insane wind storm, preventing the turbine from spinning itself apart.

Comment: @Transistor, I think I have misunderstood something with regards to zener diodes. I thought the power the diodes would need to dissipate would just be the voltage drop across the diodes (maybe 0.5V to 1V multiplied by two for the two diodes) times the portion of current that is passing through the diodes. Then the rest of the power would be dissipated braking the turbine blades.

Comment: @kevinbuiied, yes, the forward biased diode would dissipate 0.5 - 1.0 times the current but the reverse biased diode would dissipate \$ V_ZI_Z \$.

Answer (score 1):

You can place a zener+bjt clamp after rectifier so clamp is on DC side, otherwise (clamp on AC side) you would need to double it for both polarities.

[image]

Of course, the bjt has to be mounted on big heatsink. You can put a power resistor between Vcc and collector to split overall losses (like half on R and half on bjt).

Comment: The capacitor is probably unnecessary.